# Conditional Format A Cell Based on another cell number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you format a cell based on data from another cell.

This is what I do to format base on the current cell.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('table td:nth-child(9)').each(function() {
   var req = $(this).text();

        if (req ==  1) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#009933'); 
     }
        else if(req == 2) {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#ffcc00'); 
     }

     else {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff'); 
     }
    });
    return false;
   });
```

How would I format Column 5 with this the results from column 9?

If I add .parent() in-between $(this) and .css('backgroundColor

it will change the whole row.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('table tr').each(function() {
                var req = $(this)childNodes[8].text();

                if (req ==  1) {
                    $(this).childNodes[4].css('backgroundColor', '#009933'); 
                }
                else if(req == 2) {
                    $(this).childNodes[4].css('backgroundColor', '#ffcc00'); 
                }

                else {
                    $(this).childNodes[4].css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff'); 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

@Aryaman Tummalapalli

This didn't work. Trying to format column 5 with the number from column 9

Answer (score 0):

One option is to instead of having your function look for `$('table tr')` (or with appropriate restrictions on which rows you want to format) instead of `$('table td:nth-child(9)')`. Then on the inside you could do something along the lines of `var req = $(this).childNodes[8].text()`, then

```
// note the array will be 0-indexed, not 1-indexed
$(this).childNodes[4].css('background-color', '#009933');
$(this).childNodes[8].css('background-color', '#009933');`
```

to set the colors as desired (with the appropriate conditionality added), which would perform the same action on each row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get each column style is by getting the style attribute from master column like below example:

```js
$(function() {
  var newTable = $('<table>').addClass('newTable');
  var counter = 1;
  $('#master').find('tr').each(function() {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    if ($(this).find('td').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        row.append($('<td>').attr('style', $(this).attr('style')).text('Hello World ' + counter));
        counter++;
      });
    }
    newTable.append(row);
  });

  $('#layout').append($('<p>').text('This is the new table 1'));
  newTable.appendTo('#layout');
  
  
  newTable = $('<table>').addClass('newTable');
  $('#master').find('tr').each(function() {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    if ($(this).find('td').length > 0) {
      counter = 0;
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        var theStyle = '';
        switch(counter) {
          case 0:
            theStyle = 'background: blue; color: white;';
            break;
          case 1:
            theStyle = 'background: red; color: black;';
            break;
        }

        row.append($('<td>').attr('style', theStyle).text($(this).text()));
        counter++;
      });
    }
    newTable.append(row);
  });

  $('#layout').append($('<p>').text('This is the new table 2'));
  newTable.appendTo('#layout');
});
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <table id="master">
    <tr>
      <td style="background: black; color: white"> Text 1</td>
      <td style="background: red; color: black"> Text 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background: yellow; color: red"> Text 3</td>
      <td style="background: green; color: white"> Text 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```